# An error occurred when i used the 'getters' of the Vuex which said “it is not a function”，why？

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use it according to the official example , but it didn't work.

First, i exported an object which contained the function i wanted.

```
var getters = {
    getToken: (state) => {   
    if (!state.token) {
        state.token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
    return state.token
    }
}
export default getters
```

Then,i imported it in "store"

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state,    
    getters,  
    actions,  
    mutations 
})
```

Here is how it called

```
created()
    {
    
     var token=this.$store.getters.getToken(this.$store.state);
  
    }
```

Finally,An error occurred when i call its function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqqBn.png)

I want to know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you haven't provided the code that accesses the getter, so we can't tell for certain what your problem is, but I would wager based on the specific error that you're calling `getToken` as `this.$store.getters.getToken()`. This isn't how you access a getter in vuex. Instead, you simply do `this.$store.getters.getToken`, without the parentheses.

Comment: But i need to transmit a param, how can i do that?

Comment: @RuicyWu you don't need to provide the store state to the function even though it's shown as a parameter in your function definition; vuex will pass the store state to the getter function automatically. The `state` parameter isn't for you to use when accessing the getter externally, it's used to provide your getter function internal access to the store state so that you can return whichever arbitrary value you want the getter to return.